# smack RosterListener not working in Android

Tags: java, android, smack

Currently I am Working chat applicaiton using Xmpp SMACK API.but when i have called addrosterListener then i am not getting Presence current status.I have to reference of
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/RosterListener.html .please help me.

```
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {


                            Log.d("pewsence ", "pewsence Status: " + presence.getFrom());
                            Log.d("pewsence ", "pewsence to Status: "
                                    + presence.getTo() + " " + presence);

                            // Called when the presence of a roster entry is
                            // changed
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
                            // Called when a roster entries are updated.

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
                            // Called when a roster entries are removed.
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                            // Called when a roster entries are added.
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

this listener is call when activity created.I think refer to the all documents,this listener is called automatically when presense will change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you implemented Multiple user chating using XMPP server??

Answer (score 1):

```
roster = connection.getRoster();

            // Get all rosters
            Log.i("roster", "roster=" + connection.isConnected() + "-" + roster);
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            // loop through
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                Presence.Type userType = entryPresence.getType();

            }
```

Using this code ,you have to get all online or offline users.and u can chat with anyone.

Comment: Can you explain how to implement multiple user chat in XMPP?

Comment: you are not answered your question ?